# Overview of all fluidcontent FCEs

Tags: flux, fluid, fedext

For complex TYPO3 project using fluidcontent I'm looking for a tool, which show me the followering informations:

1. which FCE exists
2. how often and on what pages are they in use
3. which partials are used
4. which flux form fields are used (with name and type)
5. diposit some meta informations, e.g. tags, description ...

How would be the smartest way to implement this library in a typo3 project?

My idea is, to develop an extension which read the fluidcontent templates and show the informations in a frontend plugin with examples. But i have no idea to read out the information like "used partials" or "used flux form fields".

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FCE's are just cType elements in the tt_content table.  you can write a simple query to count the different cTypes, thus gives you a list with all the used FCE's on your site. you can know on witch page they are used because every tt_content entry has a pageUId

for the flux fields.  you will have to create a function that fetch all content elements that uses flux and then parse all the flexform fields. note that flux can also store data in other fields then flexform xml.

you can create a basic extbase plugin for this to show it in the front or backend